# PIL conversion difference between RGB and L modes

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I have several dozen images I'm using to test my deep learning application however when I converted my code to use grayscale for both testing and training I get a problem with the dimensions of the return value for grayscale mode.

Here's what I have:

```
def test_batch(self, path):
    """Evaluates a group of images on the network

           Keyword arguments:
           path -- a directory containing images to be evaluated
    """
    for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if '.jpg' in file:

                if self.channels == 3:
                    img = PIL.Image.open(os.path.join(path, file)).convert('RGB')
                else:
                    img = PIL.Image.open(os.path.join(path, file)).convert('L')
                img = img.resize((128, 128), resample=PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
                print(file)
                estimations = self.discriminator.predict(
                    np.expand_dims(np.array(img).astype('float32') / 255, axis=0))
                data = []
                for i in range(len(estimations[0])):
                    data.append('{0:2f}'.format(estimations[0][i] * 100))
```

I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 128, 128)

Normally when run with 3 channel mode (RGB mode) on my network for both training/testing the array that is input is

> (image_count, image_width, image_height, 3)

It's my assumption that the final element is the channels and as such I don't see why converting it to grayscale would eliminate this element, does anyone have any idea as to what might be going on?

**Edit:**
A quick explanation of what is going on behind the scenes is that I'm training the data with a generator with fit_generator in keras, here is the train generator definition:

```
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255,
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='grayscale' if self.channels == 1 else 'rgb'
    )
```

As you can see in the above I squash pixel values between 0-1 and apply color_mode grayscale when the channel size is 1.

Comment: I guess the functions you are sending it expect to have a 4th dimension. So the shape should still be `(n_imgs, width, height, channels)`, with channels being either 1 or 3, but right now when it's grayscale you're sending `(n_imgs, width, height)`

Comment: I already understand that what I don't understand is why applying grayscale removes the 4th dimension from an image, nor do I know how to remedy it.

Comment: Because having a channel with size 1 is not particularly useful, so PIL just removes it. The behavior is roughly the same along all types of image processing libraries---grayscale images are 2d arrays, while rgb are 3d. Anyways, you are using `expand_dims` to add the first dimension...so you can do the same to add the final one. Or just keep it easy: if `a` is an array of shape `(h, w)`, then `a[None, ..., None]` will be an array of shape `(1, h, w, 1)`.

Comment: I appreciate the help!